# Bind Data to Windows Form TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm attempting my first Windows Form project, having been entirely web based previously and experiencing some issues. I want to bind a list of objects to a TabControl and have this create the Tabs and then have a databound value accessible from the click event of each tab.

The Object I'm wanting to bind is

```
public class TreeNodeItem
{
    private NTree<string> node;

    public TreeNodeItem(NTree<string> node)
    {
        this.node = node;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.node.data; }
    }
}
```

The NTree node represents a node in an object that models data in a tree structure. I want to create a tab for each object in the list with the Value property being bound to the Tab Text property. Other posts mention binding to the ItemsSource property of the control, but Visual Studio is not giving me this property.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Stewart

Comment: Each time I've encountered such situation, I'd would either build a custom control (haven't seen one out of the box during my 5 years of dev work) or find another way to represent data. Ex. treeList control

Comment: This is the easiest thing to do in the world... if you were using `WPF` instead of `winforms`.  If you're not vested in winforms, I'd suggest using WPF instead.  I've often done data bindings to tabs and tab page contents with my view models. I can provide an example if wpf is an option.

Comment: @NathanA I know, I wish I was using WPF since this would be so easy if I were, however I am stuck with using WinForms

Comment: @Rachel I guess it all boils down to the "winforms mentality" (in contrast to the "WPF mentality" we speak about all the time). winforms doesn't really support databinding, it was not designed to, and thus you need to do all this stuff manually :S

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I was unaware of that the **binding** was a must. Although I have never seen something like this being done in a Windows Forms Application, I've decided to create a class that does this for us.

It uses the `ObservableCollection<T>` to keep track whether an object / property has been changed inside its list.

```
    public class ObservableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public ObservableList() : base()
        {
            CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(nObservableCollection_CollectionChanged);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler OnPropertyChanged;

        void nObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnPropertyChanged != null)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(new object[] { e.OldItems, e.NewItems }, null); // Call method to let it change the tabpages
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, we have to create a helper class that helps us keeping track:

```
    public class TabControlBind
    {
        public TabControlBind(TabControl tabControl)
        {
            // Create a new TabPageCollection and bind it to our tabcontrol
            this._tabPages = new TabControl.TabPageCollection(tabControl);
        }

        // Fields
        private ObservableList<TreeNodeItem> _treeNodeItems;
        private TabControl.TabPageCollection _tabPages;

        // Properties
        public ObservableList<TreeNodeItem> TreeNodeItems
        {
            get { return _treeNodeItems; }
            set
            {
                if (_treeNodeItems != value)
                {
                    _treeNodeItems = value;
                    _treeNodeItems.OnPropertyChanged += OnPropretyChanged;
                    OnPropretyChanged(null, null);
                }
            }
        }

        public TabControl.TabPageCollection TabPages
        {
            get
            {
                return this._tabPages;
            }
        }

        // Events
        private void OnPropretyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == null) // If list got set
            {
                // Remove existing tabpages
                this._tabPages.Clear();

                // Loop through all items inside the ObservableList object and add them to the Tabpage
                foreach (TreeNodeItem _treeNodeItem in this._treeNodeItems)
                {
                    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage() { Text = _treeNodeItem.Value, Tag = _treeNodeItems };
                    this._tabPages.Add(tabPage);
                }
            }
            else if (sender is object[]) // If only one (or multiple) objects have been changed
            {
                // Get OldItems and NewItems
                object[] changedItems = (object[])sender;
                // Remove OldItems
                if (changedItems[0] != null)
                {
                    foreach (dynamic oldItems in (IList)changedItems[0])
                    {
                        foreach (TabPage tab in this._tabPages)
                        {
                            if (tab.Text == oldItems.Value)
                            {
                                this._tabPages.Remove(tab);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                // Add OldItems
                if (changedItems[1] != null)
                {
                    foreach (dynamic newItems in (IList)changedItems[1])
                    {
                        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage() { Text = newItems.Value, Tag = newItems };
                        this._tabPages.Add(tabPage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a sample on how to use it:

```
    TabControlBind tabControlBinder;
    ObservableList<TreeNodeItem> treeNodeItems;

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will automatically update the TabControl
        treeNodeItems.Add(new TreeNodeItem(new NTree<string>() { data = "Test3" }));
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new list object an add items to it
        treeNodeItems = new ObservableList<TreeNodeItem>();
        treeNodeItems.Add(new TreeNodeItem(new NTree<string>() { data = "Test" }));
        treeNodeItems.Add(new TreeNodeItem(new NTree<string>() { data = "Test2" }));

        // Create a new instance of the TabControlBind class, set it to our TabControl
        tabControlBinder = new TabControlBind(tabControl);
        tabControlBinder.TreeNodeItems = treeNodeItems;
    }
```

Comment: This question is looking for a way to *bind* the TabPages collection to a collection of hierarchical objects and have them get auto-generated and auto-updated, instead of having to create tab pages manually in the code-behind like this.

Comment: See my answer again plea.se

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've removed my downvote and will be testing to see if this works or not later on. I had hoped there would be an easy way of accomplishing this without custom controls, however its looking like that won't be the case. Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried looking for an easier way too, but it seems there isn't one.. I'd love to hear from your whether this worked (for you) or not!

Comment: It does kind of work.... items do get added and removed, however the way you have the binding setup means the TabPages are recreated every time an item gets added or removed, which is not ideal. In addition, things like the Tab Headers do not properly respond to change notifications. I suspect I'm going to need to write a custom control to do this.

Comment: I've updated the code so it doesn't recreate all Tabs everytime. Also, could you explain the problem you are facing with the tab headers?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out :) The tab headers are being set directly instead of being data bound, so if I change a tab's name property from something like `"New Tab"` to `"Tab #3"`, then the change isn't made in the UI. That's probably easily fixable by using data bindings though instead of setting the property.

Comment: Cool. Also, I think you are trying to set the tab text? This isn't done by setting its `Name` property, its done by changing its `Text` property.